# DIV CSS not aligning properly in lower IE versions

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a JSP code with label and input fields in a div tag and its associated CSS.
The alignment of these fields look good in IE9+ but not in IE7.

Left div is little above and right div pretty lower. We have to support the lower IE versions too.

JSP code:-

```
<form:form...>
<DIV class="outer-left-bm">Location:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:select path="location" items="${locationList}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="desc" /></DIV>
<DIV class="outer-left-bm">Name:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:input path="Name" maxlength="20" size="20" /></DIV>
</form:form>
```

CSS :-

```
DIV.outer-left-bm {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
DIV.outer-right-bm {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

update:-

```
<form:form>
<DIV style="font-size: 0;">
<DIV class="outer-left-bm">Location:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:select path="location" items="${locationList}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="desc" /></DIV>
    <DIV class="outer-left-bm">Name:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:input path="Name" maxlength="20" size="20" /></DIV>
```

CSS:-

```
DIV.outer-left-bm {
    width:49%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
DIV.outer-right-bm {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Update2:

```
DIV.outer-left-bm {
    width:49%;  
    min-height: 0;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
DIV.outer-right-bm {
    width: 50%; 
    min-height: 0;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `display: inline-block` instead of `float`. For removing whitespace between blocks set `font-size: 0` for the container, and a pixel font-size for nested blocks like `outer-left-bm`.

```css
FORM {
    font-size: 0;
}

FORM DL,
FORM DT,
FORM DD {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

FORM DT,
FORM DD {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 49%;
}

/* Inline-block for IE7: */
*+HTML FORM DT,
*+HTML FORM DD {
    display: inline;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <dl>
        <dt>Location:</dt>
        <dd><select><option>Hello</option></select></dd>

        <dt>Name:</dt>
        <dd><input name="example" /></dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

Note that to emulate `display: inline-block` in IE7, `display: inline` with a hasLayout-toggler like `min-height: 0` (as in my code example) or `zoom: 1` are needed.

But actually, for your case, a properly marked-up table would be enough and perfectly semantic (note using `TH` elements and the `scope` attribute):

```html
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Location:</th>
            <td><select><option>Hello</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <th scope="row">Name:</th>
            <td><input name="example" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

> We have to support the lower IE versions too.

Are you sure you *really* have to? Are you aware of the current IE7’s market share? Do you live in a parallel reality? ;-) Hint: the only versions that currently matter are at least IE9+.

Comment: I know but have no options. I used inline-block and looks like the rightDiv moves to the next line now.

Comment: Have you noticed the `width: 49%` declaration? It’s important (older IEs had issues with fitting multiple elements in a row if their widths are percentage even if mathematically those values are equal to exactly 100% in total).

Comment: I have updated my question with update section and added the code for JSP and CSS. wrapped the div in another with fot:size:0; and css is updated with inlie-block and font-size in pixel. Still right div moves totally to the next row.

Comment: Have you noticed that IE7 needs `inline` instead of `inline-block`?

Comment: I’ve added a working example to the answer. Tested in IE11 running in IE7-compatibility mode.

Comment: thank you Marat Tanalin. It worked as expected.Oe more question. How do you distunguish IE5,7 from the other browsers in a style sheet(.css file).*+HTML woldnt work. However if i just have inline for ie7 it works fine. I want a sytax that controls both in CSS file.

Comment: `*+HTML` is a well-known CSS hack (like `* HTML` for IE6) that allows to apply styles specifically in IE7. (Note that real IE7 and IE8+ in IE7 compatibility mode may (and do) work differently.) IE5 does not currently matter at all, regardless of anything, even in corporate intranet sites. In general, consider using so called Conditional Comments supported in IE up to version 10 inclusive. And make sure your HTML document has a correct [DOCTYPE](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/04/html5-doctype/) declaration.

Comment: USed this *display: inline; zoom: 1; and it worked. Thanks much for your time Marat Tanalin

Comment: Marat Tanalin: I am using the css code as above in update2. What happens now is if i reduce the screen width the right side DIV wraps the error message whereas the left DIV label moves to the next line where the wrapped error msg is displayed.How Do i make the label in left stay as is irrespective of the error msg wrap?

Comment: Consider wrapping each pair in a `DIV`.

Comment: Didnt make a difference Marat Tanalin

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use separate styles for Internet Explorer 6 and Lower, here is the code to use a conditional style-sheet, place it below your other linked style-sheets, so this IE6 and Lower style-sheet overwrites whatever css you have already applied.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks. I tried same but in IE7 couple fields align and after 3/4 fields its moves down and gets misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

A `clear:both` css property on `.outer-left-bm` should suffice to make the div's align correctly.

See below link for example. There are added background colors on the two divs so we can see where they stack, and where the bounds are.

[Div align JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshnz/16L9h0qq/)

Comment: It kind of aligned the 1st 2 fields but not fully. I mean i have like 10 fields. it aligns 1st 2 and brings down the 3rd right div and totally moves the 4th right div to the 5th left div and so on.
BTW i had to use clear:both; on both left and right to make it work. It introduced scroll on the page too.